# WCF REST HttpContext.Current Async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a ASP.NET application using WCF REST running in IIS.

I need to store variables for the current HTTP request and I use `HttpContext.Current.Items` for that. I store some request Id that I set in my `global.asax` so I can use it deeper in my services. My services are doing some I/O operations so I recently changed them from synchronous to asynchronous. The problem is after the first `await`, the `HttpContext.Current` becomes null so I can't have access to my variables stored in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

My global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentRequestId"] = SetRequestId();
    }
```

My WCF contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Operation")]
    public async Task<bool> Operation()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current; // Current context available here

        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(true); // tried with both ConfigureAwait(true) and ConfigureAwait(false)

        context = HttpContext.Current; // Current context is always null here

        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to add those keys in my web.config file but it didn't change anything.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="wcf:disableOperationContextAsyncFlow" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

I am using .net 4.6.2

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
```

Is it possible to keep the `HttpContext.Current` after awaiting an asynchronous method in WCF REST with ASP.NET? Is there an alternative to `HttpContext.Current.Items` I could use to achieve what I am trying to do?

**EDIT:** This is a simplified example but the `HttpContext.Current` is used way deeper and I would prefer not to have to gather it before the await and pass it all the way down to every single method.

Comment: use your `context` after await

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Bouke I migrated to ASP.NET Core so don't have this issue anymore but if I remember correctly I had to do a custom implementation of an ambiant request context using `AsyncLocal` instead of relying on the `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem actually has nothing to do with asynchronous code; it has to do with retrieving a context variable from a (non-request) thread pool thread.

The technique recommended in the linked blog (wrapping the HttpContext and providing it to the worker thread) is extremely dangerous. HttpContext is designed to be accessed only from one thread at a time and AFAIK is not thread safe at all. So sharing it among different threads is asking for a world of hurt.

so i strongly suggest to  you fetch every thing you need from HttpContext before your async method then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue in WCF where I was losing OperationContext after awaiting task. Actually after await - the thread assigned from thread pool does not have context (basically its a different thread). We created one generic wrapper method to take care of this. Below I tried converting same in context of your question. Try it :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Operation")]
public async Task<bool> Operation()
    {
        RunWithOperationContext(()=> {
        await Task.Delay(1000); 
        return true;}
    }
public static Task<TResult> RunWithOperationContext<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            var result = await function();
            HttpContext.Current = context;
            return result;
        }
```

To David's point regarding thread safety - I thought about it and did some due diligence to ensure this is Thread Safe.

Comment: I don't see any point in using this. What is different than using directly *context* after async call.  `Operation()
    {
  var context = HttpContext.Current;  result = await something(); use context here
 }`

Comment: agree. but as i mentioned i wanted to keep this thing at single place and not repeat everytime.

Comment: I also don't see how you *keep this thing at single place*. You need `HttpContext.Current = context;` after every async call.

Comment: i meant i didn't wanted to repeat `var context = HttpContext.Current; SomeOperation(); HttpContext.Current = context;` for every `async` task

Comment: rather i will wrap my async operation with `RunWithOperationContext`

Comment: from OP: `HttpContext.Current is used way deeper` . Suppose you call `B` in `A` and `C` in `B`, and suppose all are async calls... Your solution wouldn't work here.... ( `Task A(){ await B(); } Task B(){ await C(); }` )